# Angular Material Multiple Select Options with Object

Tags: angular, firebase, select, angular-material, google-cloud-firestore

**Current Setup :**

- Angular 4
- Angular Material
- Firebase (Firestore)

**Expected Behavior :**

- Initially selecting multiple objects from my array inside my angular material multiple select.

**Current Behavior :**

- No item is initially selected.
- They get properly selected when clicking them.
- Saving them in Firebase(Firestore) work (Saving the document reference)

**Additional Note(s) :**

- If I use only an object property they do get initially selected properly.
- *classe.multiclassement* is an array of reference
- *classes* is my array of objects

**Code Sample :**

```html
<mat-select placeholder="Multiclassement" [(ngModel)]="classe.multiclassement" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let c of classes | async" [value]="c">{{c.nom}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Can you make a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) to reproduce it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since we are dealing with objects, the objects in your `multiclassesment` array have no reference to the objects in your `classes` array, so therefore Angular cannot make the binding. We can solve this by using `compareWith` (**[docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)**) like so:

```html
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareWithFn" placeholder="Multiclassement" 
            [(ngModel)]="classe.multiclassement" multiple>
```

and TS:

```ts
compareWithFn(item1, item2) {
  return item1 && item2 ? item1.nom === item2.nom : item1 === item2;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbho3s?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)